# ¿como puedo hacer un query en sequalizejs con sum y group by?

Tags: sequelize.js

necesito hacer la siguiente consulta pero sequalizejs.

**SELECT SUM(total) AS valor, cajas.fecha AS fecha FROM ventas  AS ventas INNER JOIN cajas ON (ventas.cajaId = cajas.id)GROUP BY cajas.fecha;**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [sequelize.query](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html) para pasar sql directamente.

```js
const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query("SELECT SUM(total) AS valor, cajas.fecha AS fecha FROM ventas AS ventas INNER JOIN cajas ON (ventas.cajaId = cajas.id) GROUP BY cajas.fecha;");
```